# TabBarController + NavigationController :Push and Pop issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I m using a initial Root-View controller containing Navigation Controller :

[image]

Now i want to navigate from uiviewcontroller 1.2.1 to uiviewcontroller 1.1

All conventional solutions like self.pushview and self.popView functions are not working;
They are creating another instance of that UITabBarController Containing pages ...
Plz guys join hands..
Any help will be appreciated .........

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to put little consternation on the Navigation Controller hierarchy

for navigate self navigation controller to parent navigation controller use

self.tabBarController.navigationController

USer this code

```
PUSH : [self.tabBarController.navigationController pushViewController:objNav animated:YES];

POP  : [self.tabBarController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you, this took far too long for me to find ; )

Comment: awesome answer tqs dude it saves my time alot

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3.0

PUSH:

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(ViewControleer, animated: true)
self.tabBarController?.show(ViewControleer, sender: self)
```

POP:

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.popToViewController(ViewControleer, animated: true)
```